# Entity Framework Fluent API and MultiBoundedContext

Tags: entity-framework, domain-driven-design, bounded-contexts

I have applied multi bounded context principle of domain driven design and have 3 different objects (in 3 different domain contexts) pointing to the same table in the database. As julie lerman suggested, i have a shared database model which has all my objects. This shared database model is used for code-first migrations. I also have fluent api configurations that represent foreign key relationships and column constraints on the shared database model. The question is, should i let my 3 domain specific contexts know of these fluent api configurations. I would like to validate my object graph in each of these contexts. Should i just worry about string lengths, required etc etc on these separate domain contexts? Is it necessary/good practice to configure these relationships on each of the 3 separate domain contexts?

Comment: What do you mean by "let the context know" ? Fluent mappings are defined within a DbContext, which in turn probably conceptually matches a Bounded Context in your domain. 3 different domain classes = one in each Bounded Context = one mapping in each of the 3 DbContexts.

Comment: An example would have been nicer. Let me try to give one here. Lets say we have a customer and he has made some orders. Lets say we have a customer management domain and an order management domain. The properties on the customer are Name and address. I have 2 separate bounded contexts here. The order management domain also has a customer object but only has Id, Name. The order management domain does not care about any other properties on the customer. Now i have a universal domain so i could do a code first migration to the database. This universal context has all properties from all objects.

Comment: If from fluent API i say Name cannot exceed 100 characters. so the database is constrained to those characters, should i repeat the same in the customer management domain context. I see it as the way to do validations on the customer object. If repeating my "rules" on the smaller bounded contexts is the way, should i also include the other fluent api configurations (like foreign keys etc) on the smaller domain contexts.

Comment: If you're referring to what Julie Lerman calls a "uber-context" (which is not clear in your original Q), then I guess relationship definitions should also be present at the focused context level, otherwise how could EF be able to wire up your navigation properties and all that when you query that focused DbContext ?

Comment: After working on it the last few weeks, i can confirm that the previous comment is true. Given it is a lot of work to have a multi-bounded context with multiple domains, i hope it is worth all it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you do have to repeat the fluent api configurations in the smaller domain specific models.